# In Xamarin.Forms, how to Bind to list of custom class, for ListView and print custom class properties?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

In .xaml file I am trying to bind to a listed custom class as ObeservableCollection object.
I can successfully update my variables and get the ObservableCollection updated. I can check it rendering it as:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding myCustomObservableCollection}"/>
```

However, even if I can determine the number of the entries in the list, I cannot access the properties of my custom class.
I tried with this, with no success as list's rows are empty. Even using `Text="{Binding Id}"` doesn't work since it tells me that "Id" is not a property inside myCustomViewModel:

```
<ListView
            x:DataType="vm:CustomtViewModel"
            BackgroundColor="LightSlateGray"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding myCustomObservableCollection}"
            SeparatorColor="Black">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <label Text="{Binding Source={StaticSource myCustomClass}", Path=Id}/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Of course I have inserted my custom class into the .xaml with:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:myCustomClass x:Key="myCustomClass" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And Id is one of the properties I need into the public class in my Models

```
namespace myApp.Models {
public class myCustomClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       public string Id
       {
        get => _id;
        set { 
            _id = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Id)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I wonder how to effectively read every entry of the list as an object which I could parse the properties in it.

Thanks so much

Comment: **1)** *with no success* - to get help, describe symptoms carefully. WHAT HAPPENS? Compile error? Empty list? **2)** I suspect there are typos in the code snippet in question. Is that EXACTLY the code you are running? Any warnings in VS Output pane that mention terms in your XAML?  **3)** Add to question the *declarations* of `vm:CustomtViewModel` and its `myCustomObservableCollection`. Is collection EXACTLY `public ObservableCollection<myCustomClass> { get; set; }`? If not, be sure to put in question EXACTLY what you have.

Comment: Text=“{Binding Id}”

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
I added more info in the question. Collection is set as you suggest and ask for. There were typos cause I simplified my code to offer a clear shot of the problematic area.

Comment: @Jason Valid suggestion that works in most cases as I can find out everywhere. However due to my custom handler for updating variables maybe I needed something different as I poster here, having found a way out. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also thanks to Liyun Zhang and ToolmakerSteve I came up with a solution.
Indeed it's important to set the correct x:DataType and I found out it can be done even multiple times pointing at different classes, linking different types of data
Here's my ListView in xaml now:

```
        <ListView
            x:Name="customListName"
            x:DataType="vm:CustomViewModel"
            ItemsSource="{Binding myCustomObservableCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:myCustomClass"> <!--THIS SAVED THE DAY-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" /> 
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Now the object extracted from list is correctly read referencing to its own class.

The trick is about adding `x:DataType="local:myCustomClass"` to the DataTemplate tag after I added a reference in the xaml like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:myCustomClass x:Key="myCustomClass" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

(I insert this also here for ease of reading if someone else met the same issue)

It worked like a charm!

Hope this can save someone else from headache! Cheers.

Comment: FWIW: An alternative is to remove ALL `x:DataType` properties from the XAML. If there are none, then Xamarin will attempt to bind to whatever types it finds. PRO: Easier to get right (don't have to figure out where to put `x:DataType` properties). CON: Performance: binding takes longer (though usually not enough to notice). To say this another way: if you have ANY `x:DataType` declaration, then Xamarin assumes that type is correct, even for nested elements (collections). So you have to add additional ones. [Frankly this is bizarre behavior on Xamarin's part; nested types are never same AFAIK.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Actually I tried to remove all the <strong>x:DataType</strong>, howevert the Text="{Binding Id}" contiued to complain about not being related to the right class. Maybe some other issue in the .xaml file, I guess

Comment: (It doesn't matter now, but FYI): If it complained "Id not property of class SOMECLASS", then higher up in the xaml file there must have been `x:DataType="SOMECLASS"`. There might be an `x:DataType` in the header element of the xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the official document about [Binding Cells in the ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#binding-cells)? The myCustomClass didn't have to inherit from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Just make sure there is `public ObservableCollection<myCustomClass> { get; set; }` in your viewmodel. Such as:

```
public class CustomtViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<myCustomClass> myCustomObservableCollection { get; set; }
     public CustomtViewModel()
     {
       // you can initialize the myCustomObservableCollection's data in the construction method.
     }
}
```

In addition, I see you used the `x:DataType="vm:CustomtViewModel"` for the listview. The official document said:

> Set an x:DataType attribute on a VisualElement to the type of the object that the VisualElement and its children will bind to.

So you can just binding the Id like Jason said:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Label Text={Binding Id}/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In addition, you can refer to the official sample about listview mvvm binding on the github.This is the [viewmodel's code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/ViewModels/MonkeysViewModel.cs) and the [page's code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/Views/MonkeysPage.xaml).

Comment: Thanks a lot, unluckily for this design I got two issues:
1- I do make the update for the binding variables outside the view (outside the page) and also outside the ViewModel
2- even implementing the x:DataType="vm:CustomViewModel" my {Binding Id} shows an error since it cannot actually find any property called Id inside the ViewModel. However, thanks to this point you suggested I came up with a solution

Comment: You can try to change the myCustomClass such as `public class myCustomClass{ public string Id{get ; set; }}` and then use `{Binding Id}`. @MicheleRava